# Align text baseline to bottom of div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, baseline

I am trying to align the **baseline** of some text in a `div` to the very bottom edge of said `div` (such that characters like `g` and `j` would actually overflow the div)

I can only seem to align the bottom edge of the text element to the bottom edge of the `div`.
I have tried to use `vertical-align` with values `baseline` and `bottom` on the inner and outer element, but without success.

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
  TEST gjp ABC
  </span>
</div>
```

I also want to be able to *offset* the baseline from the bottom of the div (e.g. `bottom: 10px;` positions the baseline of the text *10px* from the bottom edge of the div).

**Edit:** I should also mention that I want to keep the `position: absolute;` property on the `span` element, because I want to freely position multiple of those in the parent `div.`

For example, here, **A**'s baseline should be at the bottom edge of the div, **B**'s should be *10px* above it and **C**'s *20px*:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
  A
  </span>
  <span style="left: 50px; bottom: 10px;">
  B
  </span>
  <span style="left: 100px; bottom: 20px;">
  C
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `::before` pseudo element with 100% height and `display: inline-block;` and use it to vertically align the `<span>` to the baseline:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>TEST gjp ABC</span>
</div>
```

You can apply the same idea to the span itself, but you'll have to state the height of the span:

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1em;
  background: red;
}

span::before {
  display: inline-block;  
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">gjp</span>
  <span style="left: 50px; bottom: 10px;">gjp</span>
  <span style="left: 100px; bottom: 20px;">gjp</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but I want to keep the `position:absolute;` in the `span` because I want to freely position **multiple** of those `span` elements in the parent div. I didn't state this explicitly in my original question, so I'll edit it

Comment: sorry to bother again, but now there seems to be a space inserted between the `::before` element and the actual text in the `span`. I need the left edge of the `span` at the position I specify. If the gap were consistent I could just shift the `span` to the left by a certain amount, but the gap varies with font size...

Comment: That's a white space. You can remove the white space in the HTML or use one of the other methods proposed here. I've updated the HTML to remove the white space.

Comment: Oh I see. I though it added a space between the `::before` element and the text, and since `::before` is only a pseudo-element and not specified inside the html code, I though I can't get rid of it by removing spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also decrease line-height to 0.8em so the text overflow the span .

```html
<div style="height: 80px; width: 300px; background: #ff5; position: relative;">
 <span style="font-size: 30px; position: absolute; left:0; bottom:0;line-height:0.8em;">
  TEST gjp ABC
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the span with a `line-height` equal to 0 then consider a hidden character that will control the alignment. You may need to adjust the value based on the font used:

```css
.container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

.container>span {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container>span:before {
  content: "\200B";
  vertical-align: -0.35em;/* Adjust this */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>TEST gjp ABC</span>
  <span style="font-family:arial;right:0;left:auto;font-size:20px">TEST gjp ABC</span>
</div>
```

You can also simply consider a translation:

```css
.container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ff5;
  position: relative;
}

.container>span {
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  transform: translateY(-0.35em);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>TEST gjp ABC</span>
  <span style="font-family:arial;right:0;left:auto;font-size:20px">TEST gjp ABC</span>
</div>
```